# How can i set an image to be in the bottom left corner of an activity AND in the background

Tags: android, background-image

I want to set the logo of my app to the bottom left hand side of the screen and be in the background. the reason i want to do this is to allow the users to modify the background colors which would not be possible if i simply set the entire activity or layout background to an image to give same impression.

Another way of asking this is how do i set an image to bottom left hand corner and below other controls?

Comment: Simply use a RelativeLayout and set the ImageView properties `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" is generally by default true but still its a good practice to mention specifically

Comment: Where do i put my RelativeLayout - Left implies the image will be at top left instead of bottom left. Where do i put the rest of my controls, i want tohe activities controls to appear on top of my image, this dfoesnt seem to answer the 'background' part of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know if i understand correct. but what you ask is pretty simple.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="#ffff00" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<!--         Put your views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

you can change the frame layout's background as you wish and keep logo on bottom left corner.
Also you can set your LinearLayout (which you can use any layout. it is up to you) background to transparent so you will see background. and any extra view inside the linear layout (your view container) will be on top always.

Comment: Will this ensure that the image will be 'under' the activities controls and give impression of a background image?

Comment: yes. if you put your controls inside the inner layout (in this case LinearLayout) they will be on top of your image (logo).

Comment: but be sure that there will not be too many layout nested. you can check google's documents for that matter.

Comment: Is it the gravity attr that makes the image appear 'below' the rest of the controls?

Comment: no. in FrameLayout. first item in order will be on bottom. like stack. so in this case LinearLayout will be the last item and it is on top. gravity will only ensure the 2 dimensional pozition.

Comment: sorry,crossed wires... by ;'below' i mean under the ther controls in the 'z-index' sense. So i need this to be in the background. Where in your code ensures this? I want other controls to appear ontopof it

Comment: last view inside framelayout will on top. you can see by trying. put some button inside linear layout. ofcourse enought to fill screen. they will be on top of logo. it is pretty simple actually. frame layout is like stack. but any item inside it can be cantrolled by gravity or margin.

Comment: be sure to give transparent background to LinearLayout (or your version of inner container). use alpha with color code. i mean 8 digit. it will make bacground (frame layout and other contents) visible

Comment: Fantatsic, that works. One more thing; i set margin in image to 0 as i want the square image snug into the corner, as its not a square but a rectangle the image has a transparent border on top and bottom which stops it going along the bottom border

Comment: I can set width and height to wrap_contents but what i i want to change width?

Comment: use logo image in backgroud attribute. not on src. or vice versa. and i believe it will handle that problem.

Comment: if you have more problem on layout. you can put your xml here so i can make proper adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_desired_full_background">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So where do i put my layout with all its controls? I want the image to be in the background right? WIill this not result in the image being in the foreground interfering with allt he controls?

Comment: you want the logo as the background in the bottom-left corner? just like a footer logo?

Comment: if my assumption of previous comment is right, then you need to use FrameLayout as @Engin suggested.

Comment: Not like a footer logo, a footer logo suggests it is on same z-index level as my controls